# Adding a button inside an image

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, xcode

CGRect frame = CGRectMake(round((self.view.bounds.size.width - kImageWidth) / 2.0),
                              kTopPlacement, kImageWidth, kImageHeight);
    self.containerView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame] autorelease];
    [self.view addSubview:self.containerView];

```
// create the initial image view
frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, kImageWidth, kImageHeight);
self.mainView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:frame] autorelease];
self.mainView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:imagePath];
```

I want to put a button inside mainview.image. How can I do it?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to create one button.

and add mainView as a subview to that button using code:

```
 [btnButton addSubView:mainView];
```

and add this button as a subview to your ViewContoller 's view

```
[self.view addSubView:btnButton];
```

Answer (score 0):

Might be easier to use a [UIButton](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html) and add the image as the background.

Look at the section on Configuring Button With Images

You could also add a clear button (using the UIButtonTypeCustom) on top of the UIImageView if you want the button to only take up part of the image.